# How do I get the CPU socket type? (C#)

Tags: c#, wmi, cpu

I'm developing an application which needs to check the CPU socket type at some point.
How can I get the proper socket?
I tried to do it via WMI using Win32_Processor class, but I couldn't find descriptions of modern sockets at MSDN help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx) There are only old kinds of sockets. Where can I get the updated info for this stuff? Or maybe there is an alternate way to get a socket information?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are just looking for a list of socket types that exist, or you need to get the socket type from Win32_Processor?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a list of socket types that exist. Would be awesome to get an up-to-date list with the likes of 2011 or 1155.

Comment: I mean. Did you check the link I mentioned above? Check an UpgradeMethod property of Win32_Processor, it can get me the socket type, but I need to know which number means the specific socket. I need that "table" of sockets including the newest ones, not just the old things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Management.Instrumentation` to query `Win32_Processor`

Example:

```
string processorSocket;

var processor = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
if (processor != null)
{
    processorSocket = (string)processor["SocketDesignation"];
}

// returns: Socket M2
```